# Partitions, weights and polynomials with roots on the unit circle

Tags: co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, zeroes

Let us consider the set $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and all of its partitions into exactly $m$ blocks, but let us allow each block to be internally ordered. For example, taking $n=6$ and $m=2$, we will distinguish between $\{(1,2),(3,5,4,6)\}$ and $\{(1,2),(5,3,4,6)\}$, but we will consider $\{(1,2),(3,5,4,6)\}$ and $\{(3,5,4,6),(1,2)\}$ as the same object.

For each partition $\pi$ of $[n]$ into $m$ parts as above, we will define a notion of *weight* as follows: for each part of $P$ of $\pi$, consider the number of elements in $P$ that are smaller (as positive integers) than the first element of $P$, this will be denoted by $w(P)$. Then, the weight of $\pi$ is defined by
$$w(\pi) := \sum_{P\in \pi} w(P)$$

For instance, the weight of $\pi_1=\{(1,2),(3,5,4,6)\}$ is $w(\pi_1) = 0 + 0 = 0$, the weight of $\pi_2=\{(1,2),(5,3,4,6)\}$ is $w(\pi_2) = 0 + 2 = 2$, etc.

Denote by $W(\ell,n,m)$ the number of partitions $P$ of $[n]$ into $m$ parts and having weight $\ell$.

> **Problem:** Show that for each $n,m$, the polynomial: $$P_{n,m}(x) := \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-m} W(\ell,n,m)\, x^{\ell}$$ has all of its complex
> roots lying on the unit circle $|z|=1$.

For example, if $n=6$ and $m=2$, one may calculate:
$$P_{6,2}(x) = 274 + 404x + 444x^2+404x^3+274x^4.$$

For $n=7$ and $m=3$,

$$P_{7,3}(x)=1624 + 2954x + 3444x^2 + 2954x^3 + 1624x^4$$

I was originally interested in proving that $P_{n,m}(x)$ was log-concave, and I discovered that this unit-circle-rootedness pattern holds for all small values of $n$ and $m$.

Comment: I suggest to do a change of variables, to map unit circle onto the real line. then you want to show real-rootedness. There are many approaches here, the easiest is to find some type of recurrence which preserves real-rootedness.

Comment: Sure, but the resulting combinatorial interpretation of the coefficients might be much less nice than in the original basis. Also, there are many approaches for unit-circle-rootedness too (such as the Lee-Yang theorem).

Comment: The Lee-Yang Circle Theorem gives a general class of polynomials whose zeros all lie on the unit circle, but I don't know if it's related to the question. For a clear statement not involving physics, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3169.pdf.

Comment: You can also work with the unit circle directly, by using thm 6.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0401.pdf
It might be easier if you first find a multivariate generalization of your polynomials which are stable

Comment: One can show that $\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 1}P_{n,m}(x) t^m\frac{q^n}{n!}=\left( \frac{1-qx}{1-q}\right)^{t/(1-x)}$.

Comment: @RichardStanley That sounds interesting! I tried to relate this with the unit-circle-rootedness problem, but it doesn't seem to be easy.  Relatedly, I was able to prove the following recurrence $P_{n,m}(x) = (n-1)(x+1)\,P_{n-1,m}(x)+P_{n-1,m-1}(x)-(n-1)(n-2)x\,P_{n-2,m}(x)$. Maybe this is useful somehow (it reminds me a lot to recurrences that people use to prove that polynomials are real-rooted, but here I want unit-circle-rootedness and I have this annoying minus sign in the recurrence).

Comment: It seems that with some small exceptions, either $P_{n,m}(x)$ is irreducible or $P_{n,m}(x)=(x+1)Q_{n,m}(x)$, where $Q_{n,m}(x)$ is irreducible. Moreover, the Galois groups of $P_{m,n}(x)$ (when irreducible) and $Q_{n,m}(x)$ are always hyperoctahedral groups. More computation would be desirable.